# Getting document is not defined , from document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, atom-editor

I am learning JavaScript and I am using Atom (Text Editor).
On my HTML file I got only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button id="displayTodosButton">Display Todos</button>
    <button>Toggle Todos</button>
</body>
</html>
```

On my javascript file, I am simply trying to access the "Display todos" button using this:

```
var displayTodosButton = document.getElementById('displayTodosButton')
```

I was watching a video, and the instructor is using [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/), and he accesses the button just fine, yet on Atom I get the  "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: The script is in the head, the element is in the body, so the script probably runs before the element is available, but that would just give you `null`, not the error you're describing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a simple IDE/Text Editor

Comment: *"yet on Atom I get"* Do you mean that your editor is highlighting a line in the code and warning you that `document` is undefined? Not that the *browser* is doing that?

Comment: `document` is undefined? You have serious problems.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes,  it only happens on Atom

Comment: Are you trying to write an extension for Atom?

Comment: Are you using something like JS Hint from within Atom?

Comment: If it's just in the editor, as in it doesn't understand that `document` doesn't need to be defined elsewhere in the scripts, it doesn't matter?

Comment: try running your code, check the console and see if it says the same or if it actually works

Comment: What if you use `window.document`?

Answer (score 5):

> yet on Atom I get

If you really mean that Atom, your text editor, is highlighting it and showing you a warning that `document` is undefined, it's just that Atom doesn't realize you're running that code in a browser context where `document` will be defined.

It probably has a setting where you can tell it that you'll be running the code in a browser, so it can assume the default set of globals (`window`, `document`, etc.).

---

If the code in `script.js` is just what you've shown, although the error Atom is showing you won't be a problem (because in the browser, `document` will not be `undefined`), you'll get `null` back from `getElementById` because your code runs before the element exists. Again, this is assuming that code is on its own, not (say) inside a `DOMContentLoaded` handler or similar.

Unless you have a good reason to do it (and there aren't many), putting `script` elements in the `head` is an anti-pattern. Put them in `body`, right at the end, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. That way, any elements defined above them will have been created by the browser before your code runs.

Answer (score 2):

You have hit some menu option or key combination which is trying to execute the JS file using Node.js.

Your code, however, is designed to run, embedded in a web page, using the APIs supplied by web browsers.

Web browsers, under those circumstances, will provide a `document` object. Node.js will not.

You need to **open the HTML document in a web browser**. The [open in browser](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser) extension might be useful.

You can see any error reports using the Developer Tools that every major browser supplies.

(NB: The first error you will then encounter is explained by [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to run the JS code with the "script" package in atom (which is in a NodeJS context). What you actually want to do, is to run it in your web browser. So just open `index.html` in your favorite browser and see the magic :)