# ReferenceError: document is not defined (atom ide)

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here][[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWD8u.png)1]When I run my code in Atom IDE, this error comes up:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

How can I fix this?

JS:

```
var images1 = "images/dice"+ randomNumber1 +".png";
document.querySelector(".dice .img1").setAttribute("src",images1);
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 1</p>
        <img class="img1" src="images/dice6.png">
      </div>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 2</p>
        <img class="img2" src="images/dice6.png">
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>

  <footer>
    www  App Brewery  com
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225295/getting-document-is-not-defined-from-document-getelementbyid

Comment: Clean you question. Remember to include code as text.